Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (10054)
I am trying to access the on premises database from an Azure web app that I have deployed. But I am unable to receive any data from the API call.
I was trying to alter CipherString = SEC@LEVEL = 2 to CipherString = SEC@LEVEL = 0 and it was working sometimes but most of the times it is just showing this error.

ERROR:root:Health check failed. SQLState: 08001, Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (10054) (SQLDriverConnect)')


Aside... all supported versions of Microsoft SQL Server can use TLS 1.2 or better encryption out of the box. You should encourage your business to upgrade their SQL Server to a supported version rather than further compromise their data security by hobbling TLS communications over the open internet.

ERROR:root:Health check failed. SQLState: 08001, Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (10054) (SQLDriverConnect)')

When the target server has unsupported TLS version, then you may get above error. You should use TLS 1.2 version for SQL server.  TLS 1.2 support for SQL Server 2017 on Windows, SQL Server 2016, SQL Server 2014, SQL Server 2012, SQL Server 2008, and SQL Server 2008 R2.
Connect SQL server to SSMS and run select @@VERSION command, it will give the SQL server version as shown below:

MSSQL 2019 version will support TLS 1.2 version, for more information you can refer to the below documents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/tls-1-2-support-microsoft-sql-server#additional-fixes-needed-for-sql-server-to-use-tls-12

[08001][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 - Ubuntu 22.04


